# How public key is derieved from private key in bitcoin?

Tags: math, bitcoin

I would like to find a step-by-step explanation for the process of generating a public key from a private key in Python 3.
I'm using this library: https://pypi.org/project/bitcoin/

I have read this answer here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25024/how-do-you-get-a-bitcoin-public-key-from-a-private-key
but I couldn't get it.

I would like to understand the exact math is going on in the library I mentioned.
let's assume we have the following private key in hex:
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c1
how can I generate its public key (x,y)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first number in the thread you refer to is brilliant. What exactly you do not understand there?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048922/private-key-to-public-key-bitcoin-formula-python-3-0/66399550#66399550 where I answer a similar question, and this other link: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/102994/how-convert-bitcoin-privat-key-compression-to-public-address/103046#103046